# Programming with Riley at Christmas

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> *My prefix is a built-in python function.*
>
> *My suffix is a built-in python class.*
>
> *My infix is a built-in python operator.*
>
> *My whole is a tasty Christmas treat*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are:

> **MINT**!

*My prefix is a built-in python function.*

> **[MIN()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_min.asp)** is a built-in function to find the lowest of a set or list of values.

*My suffix is a built-in python class.*

> Variables or objects of the **[INT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_numbers.htm)** class are positive or negative whole numbers with no decimal point.

*My infix is a built-in python operator.*

> The **[IN](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-membership-identity-operators-not-not/)** operator enables the user to check if a particular value occurs *within* a particular range or sequence.

*My whole is a tasty Christmas treat*

> Many sweet treats at Christmas include **MINT** as an ingredient - generally *peppermint*. Yum!